# Flutter - Android Emulator Fullscreen Mode

Tags: android, flutter, fullscreen

Black bar at the top of the Android emulator in full screen mode
Did I do something wrong?

*I am new to stackoverflow and cannot add images yet*
[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cN9r.png)

Virtual Device Settings:
Pixel 5  6.0 1080x2340 xxhdpi
Android API 33 x86_64
Startup orientation: Portrait
Emulated Performance:

- Graphics: Hardware - GLES 2.0
- Boot option: Quick boot
- Multi-Core CPU 4

Host: Windows 11

Flutter doctor: No issues found!

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Root(),
    );
  }
}

class Root extends StatelessWidget {
  const Root({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      color: Colors.red,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the emulator and recreated it. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this;

```
void main(){

  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: This removes the black bar, but as soon as I remove the status bar it does nothing. I can't really hide the status bar icons and want the app bar to be at the top. Thanks anyway